# How can I solve Spring Boot with Websphere Traditional 8.5.5 jaxb conflict issues?

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

I'm using external lib folder changed the class loading to parent last, I have been trying to solve the issue with other questions' answers but unfortunately couldn't get it working. It seems spring couldn't initialize one of its classes and jaxb is conflicting with websphere.

Spring using jaxb-2.3.1

Websphere using jaxb-2.2.10

Stack trace:-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.xml.xpath.Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory (initialization failure)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$146.000000001A9AF6A0.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:721) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:620) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1452) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:641) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1034) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5482) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5698) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83) [?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287) [?:1.8.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263) [?:1.8.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:673) [?:1.8.0]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:1.8.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257) [?:1.8.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096) [?:1.8.0]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831) [?:1.8.0]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813) [?:1.8.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118) [bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf151903.01]]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:503) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:337) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:532) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.xml.xpath.Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory (initialization failure)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.xml.xpath.Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:96) ~[?:2.9 (12-19-2018)]
    at org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionFactory.createXPathExpression(XPathExpressionFactory.java:73) ~[spring-xml-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.version.AbstractAddressingVersion.createNormalizedExpression(AbstractAddressingVersion.java:117) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.version.AbstractAddressingVersion.<init>(AbstractAddressingVersion.java:89) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.initDefaultStrategies(AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.java:107) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.<init>(AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.java:98) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractActionEndpointMapping.<init>(AbstractActionEndpointMapping.java:38) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport.annotationActionEndpointMapping(WsConfigurationSupport.java:120) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81d39527.CGLIB$annotationActionEndpointMapping$6(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81d39527$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d4e95288.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81d39527.annotationActionEndpointMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 77 more
```

Comment: Would you be able to check earlier to see why the initialization failed the first time? The stack indicates that this is an "initializationAlreadyFailed" situation. You might be able to find that by searching for `<clinit>` in a stack trace. Also... do you really NEED parent-last class loading here? JAXB is included in the server.

Comment: @Jarid initialization failed because of `XPathFactory.newInstance()` in spring `Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory` class couldn't create XPathFactory instance while refreshing the spring container `SpringServletContainerInitializer` as explained in the stack trace. I don't need parent-last class loading it was a suggestion from another answer but didn't make any difference.

Comment: The stack you provided only tells us that `Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory` failed to initialize at some point earlier in the process - that's why `J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed` is at the top of the stack (static initialization is attempted once, and if it fails, the class is marked as "failed" by the JVM an can never be defined successfully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by upgrading spring boot version, although I didn't manage to resolve the issue by many ways upgrading spring boot version seems to work for me.